# How to take document per line when combining multiple documents?

Tags: python-2.7, merge, documents

Hello everyone,
                  I have 3000 documents with me. I want to combine the content of those 3000 documents in one single document. I used

```
cat *.html > Combined_Text.txt
```

command to do the process. But, I would like to have the data of one document per line in the Combined_Text.txt which means I should just be having 3000 lines of content (one document per line). How to do it? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The following command will remove new lines from every html and then append the files to each other in `Combined_Text.txt`.

```
 for f in *.html; do cat $f | tr -d '\n' >> Combined_Text.txt; echo "" >> Combined_Text.txt; done;
```

That second echo seems to inelegant, I'm sure there is a better way to put the files on their own lines, but it does the job.